# How to select all attributes of the current node? (XPATH)

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to select all the attributes of the current node and then display them on screen.

This would have the functionality of a navigator that will tell you all the attributes within the node you are on.

I am trying with ".*" "@*" ".@" but nothing seems to work. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use `@*` selector to select all attributes:

```
element.Select("@*");
```

Comment: +1. You beat me. Almost unanswerable question since answer is too short :)